# Create an array of Types

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm writing some codes that uses reflection, but I realized array of types behave somewhat surprisingly.

When I try to create an array the normal way, like this:

```
Type[] params = new Type[2];
```

I receive an error saying

> Class name is not valid at this point

Why is it saying that? How is Type different from the other types?

Comment: Arrays of Type behave just like any other array; replace `Type` with `string` or anything else, and you'll see the same error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the fact that it is an array of `Type`.  It's because `params` is a keyword.  Either escape the name (which is done by prefixing it with an @ symbol) or use a different name.